# Garbage values in matching two matrices (having double type values)

Tags: c++, opencv

I have two 2D matrices which consist of elements having`double` datatype. I want to match these values using the formula

```
value =  | (a[i][j] - b[i][j]) |  / ( 1 + a[i][j] + b[i][j] )
```

**My code:**

```
double ColorCorrelogram::correlogramMatching(double (&a)[Num_colorBin][Distance_Range]  , double (&b)[Num_colorBin][Distance_Range])
{
    for(int i=0; i<Num_colorBin; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<Distance_Range; j++)
        {
            double value = (    (std::abs)( a[i][j] - b[i][j] ) )   /   (1  +   a[i][j] +   b[i][j]);
            cout<<"\n( "<<a[i][j] <<"  and  "   <<b[i][j]<<"  )"<<"  gave  "<<value<<"    ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Matrix - 1:**

[image]

**Matrix - 2:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

***Problem:***

- Why some values are *`negative`* in the **Result**, when i have already used `std::abs`.
- There are some garbage values as can be seen in the ***line-2*** in results.

Comment: You calculated `value` but printed `confidenceValue`.

Comment: @T.C.: sorry, that was by mistake because i wanted to post the simplified code at SO. But i am still getting the `negative` values when i use `value` instead of `confidenceValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the code in the form

```
((std::abs)(double))/double
```

instead of

```
(std::abs)(double/double)
```

and std::abs doesn't work like a type conversion.